# Could not able to trace how Map is working in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

In this below code, instead of seeing output as

```
0 -> 1 2
1 -> 2 3
..
..
99 ->100 101
```

I am getting output as,

```
0 -> 100 101
1 -> 100 101
...
99 -> 100 101
```

Please help me how to resolve this problem, where exactly it is going wrong?
While debugging I found, in first iteration it stores

```
0 -> 1 2
```

2nd iteration it it updates like,

```
0 -> 2 3
1 -> 2 3
```

Why?

```
class abc{
    public:
        int x, y;
};
std::map<int, abc*> MAP;
int main()
{
    abc *ab;
    ab = new abc();
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ab->x = i + 1;
        ab->y = i + 2;
        MAP.insert(std::pair<int, abc*>(i, ab));
    }
    map<int, abc*>::iterator it;
    for(it = MAP.begin(); it != MAP.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << "->" << it->second->x <<" "<< it->second->y << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why use `MAP.insert`? `MAP[i] = ab` is cleaner.

Comment: leemes and crashmstr:- It depends on requirement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ab = new abc();
```

You have only one `abc` allocated. And you keep modifying it in the loop and reinserting the pointer to it. So all the `second` values of the map are pointing to the same single `abc`.

---

```
abc *ab;
// ab = new abc();

//
//
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

    ab = new abc();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ab->x = i + 1;
    ab->y = i + 2;
    MAP.insert(std::pair<int, abc*>(i, ab));
}
```

Comment: Actually it's not ab which gets modified but the object ab points to. So when inserting it into the map, not the modified object but the unmodified address pointing to it gets inserted.

Comment: @leemes ya :) while I was writing I was also thinking ok somethig is odd here. But the rush to answer before someone else :) I will rewrite it now.

Answer (score 1):

You are always refering to the same address with :

```
abc *ab;
ab = new abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
abc *ab;
ab = new abc();
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ab->x = i + 1;
    ab->y = i + 2;
    MAP.insert(std::pair<int, abc*>(i, ab));
}
```

Since you store pointer to class objects into the map. If you do the above, inside your for loop,you keep changing the values of the pointed object, not storing new objects into map.

Try the following:

```
abc *ab;
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

    ab = new abc();
    ab->x = i + 1;
    ab->y = i + 2;
    MAP.insert(std::pair<int, abc*>(i, ab));
}
```